# How to change date field format on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display link and populate it with 3 fields

```
*<a href="" id="{!routeReference.id}"> {!routeReference.Status__c} - {!routeReference.Date__c} </a>*
```

I want to display date like - "TestStatus - Nov 28, 2015"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a  href="">{!routeReference.Status__c}-
    {!CASE( MONTH( routeReference.Date__c ) , 1, "Jan", 2, "Feb", 3, "Mar", 4, "Apr", 5, "May", 6, "Jun", 7, "Jul", 8, "Aug", 9, "Sep", 10, "Oct", 11, "Nov", "Dec")} {!DAY(routeReference.Date__c)}, {!YEAR(routeReference.Date__c)}
</a>
```

This will display as expected  `"TestStatus - Nov 28, 2015"`

Answer (score 2):

```
 <a  href="">{!routeReference.Status__c}-
 <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMM d','  yyyy}">
        <apex:param value="{!routeReference.Date__c} " /> 
    </apex:outputText>
</a>
```